# awk: Print lines starting with a pattern only if the next line also starts with the same pattern

Tags: awk

I read a similar post titled **"Print lines matching a pattern only if the next line does not match the pattern"** for which the solution mentioned is

```
awk 'a=/^O/{x=$0} !a&&x{print x;x=0;}' myfile
```

I just wanted to know how would the above command change if I want to print all lines in a file whose next line too start with same pattern as the current line.

e.g

file text contains:

```
abc this is a line
def
abc this is line 2
ghi
abc this is line 3
abc this is line 4
jkl
mno
abc this is line 5
jkl
abc this is line 6
abc this is line 9
jkl
```

the command should be such that only following lines should be printed:

```
abc this is line 3
abc this is line 6
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks to all who helped. Editing original question a bit here to satisfy the requirement as the below won't help when there are multiple similar lines.

What would be the awk command if all lines in a file such that next line ends with a different pattern are to be printed.

E.g: if file contains:

```
Student name is A
Student name is B
Student name is C
result for C is pass
Student name is D
result for D is pass
Student name is E
result for E is pass
Student name is F
result for F is pass
Student name is G
result for G is pass
Student name is H
Student name is I
result for I is pass
```

How can I use awk to print all lines with Student name where the students are not pass.
So for above example the lines printed should be:

```
Student name is A
Student name is B
Student name is H
```

Can I print all lines which start with Student where their following line doesn't end with the string PASS using awk?

Comment: What should happen if 3 or more consecutive lines start with this pattern?

Comment: You're thinking of this backwards. If you're turning over playing cards and you turn over a king it's hard to do something at that point based on whether or not your next card will be an ace because you haven't seen your next card yet. On the other hand if you turn over an ace it's extremely easy to do something if your previous card was a king because you've already seen it. Same 2 cards in the same order but THINKING about it differently shows you a hard solution and an easy solution. Avoid trying to do things based on what's coming next if you can do it based on what came previously.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**:

For the updated requirements:

> Can I print all lines which start with Student where their following line doesn't end with the string PASS using awk?

```
$ awk '$NF != "pass" && p0 {print p0} {p0 = ($1 == "Student") ? $0 : ""}' sw.txt
Student name is A
Student name is B
Student name is H
```

*Previous*:

> print all lines in a file whose next line also starts with same pattern as the current line.

```
$ awk '$1 == p1 {print p0} {p1 = $1; p0 = $0}' sw.txt
abc this is line 3
abc this is line 6
```

If the current first field literally matches that of the previous line, we print the previous line.

(I should note that while your question refers to lines starting with the same "pattern", based on the sample input and output I've taken that to mean simple string matching and not to do with regular expressions as "pattern" normally refers to in the context of awk.)

Comment: perhaps note that this is not a pattern match but rather a literal match (equality).  Question is vague as well.

Comment: This would print an initial blank line if the first line of the input file was blank or started with a value that evaluates numerically to zero regardless of the value of the 2nd line. @codecrazy46 - also, clarify if you always want a string or numeric or regexp comparison as right now you'd find you get string matches for some values and numeric for others (so `0` == `0.00`, etc.). Never use the word `pattern` on its own in software requirements as it's ambiguous - at least use `string` or `regexp` (or in this case `numeric`) AND if you want a full or partial match (does `abcde` match `abc`?)

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have added a few lines to the original question mentioning the actual requirement. Is there an awk one liner I can use for this purpose?

Comment: See the edit for a possible solution given the new requirements.

Comment: Thanks jas for the help. It works great now. Just out of interest in this wanted to ask how would the command change if: 1. first line was connected like Student_name_is_A so there are no distinct words but second line remains in the same format as mentioned in the edited question.2. Also how would command change in case the second line also doesn't have distinct words but separator between words is _ like result_for_I_is_pass? Thanks again.

Comment: Also in the above some lines don't start with only Student, they can start like Old_Student as well. So in the file few lines could also be Old_Student_name_is_A. Please help me with these kind of scenarios.